# How to change the pylab window background color?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to change the background color of matplotlib interactive (pylab) window (from gray to white) ? How can I do ?

Comment: This answer to my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804005/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-background-color

Comment: possible duplicate of [change background \*without\* a frame with matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897527/change-background-without-a-frame-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I already stated in the comments, I found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804005/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-background-color) Stack Overflow post.

But the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897527/change-background-without-a-frame-with-matplotlib) link also gives the answer.

This shows that the results of the search stackoverflow is not good enough, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question!