# change background *without* a frame with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given this code,

```
from pylab import *
ion()
axes(frameon = 0, aspect = 1, polar = 1)
grid (True)
```

I get the window, containing the axes, where I can plot what I need.

I want to change the background of this window from the standard gray to another color.

I do not want to use a frame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify an argument to the `facecolor` parameter when calling `figure()`:

```
from pylab import *
ion()
figure(facecolor='white') # Or any other color
axes(frameon = 0, aspect = 1, polar = 1)
grid(True)
```

[image]