# Matplotlib figure facecolor alpha while saving (background color, transparency)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

A previous question dealt with using `savefig()` to save with the same facecolor (background color) as is displayed on screen, namely:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('blue')
fig.savefig('foo.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())
```

[Matplotlib figure facecolor (background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804005/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-background-color)

(Using `savefig()` requires us to respecify the background color.)

I can also specify an alpha for transparency, e.g.: [How to set opacity of background colour of graph wit Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581504/how-to-set-opacity-of-background-colour-of-graph-wit-matplotlib)

`fig.patch.set_alpha(0.5)`

I can't find a way to make the figure with a transparent facecolor save as it appears onscreen.  The documentation seems incomplete on this: http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#save-transparent-figures - the actual saving isn't showing.  Using `transparent=True` with `savefig()` does not have the desired effect of making the facecolor transparent, instead it seems to make everything except axes legend transparent on top of that color (including graph backgrounds).

EDIT: Some relevant extracts of code:

```
def set_face_color(fig, facecolor):
    if facecolor is False:
        # Not all graphs get color-coding
        facecolor = fig.get_facecolor()
        alpha = 1
    else:
        alpha = 0.5
    color_with_alpha = colorConverter.to_rgba(
        facecolor, alpha)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor(color_with_alpha)

def save_and_show(plt, fig, save, disp_on, save_as):
    if save:
        plt.savefig(save_as, dpi=dpi_file, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(),
                    edgecolor='none')
    if disp_on is True:
        figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        figManager.window.showMaximized()
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.close('all')
```

It might be possible to combine these, but I often call `set_face_color()` at the beginning of a graphing function before I build up a grid of subplots and then `save_and_show()` toward the end.  I guess it should work in either place, but optimally I'd prefer to keep the functions separate and be able to extract the alpha to pass to `savefig()` from the final fig.

EDIT 2 - Worth a thousand words

Alpha = 0.5 on the left, 1 on the right.

[image: image of code below]

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
fig.set_facecolor('b')
plt.plot(t, t)
fig2 = plt.figure()
fig2.set_facecolor('b')
plt.plot(t,t)
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you want a figure with a transparent background? Anyhow, you should be able to set the facecolor using a 4-tuple RGBA color argument, i.e. `facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0)`.

Comment: Just using alpha to shade the color I'm using a bit (alpha = 0.5 for this code).  I tried using `colorConverter.to_rgba()` so I could just use `set_facecolor()` and skip the `set_alpha()`, but apparently `fig.savefig(..., facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())` either doesn't return the 4-tuple or ignores the alpha.  I'm setting the facecolor elsewhere in the program - color coding it to data values so when I flip through plots I can quickly sort them - so while I could carry the value around and pass it to `savefig` later I'd most prefer to be able to extract it from the fig.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you're trying to achieve. Could you add an image to your original post?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. In my case I have a white background figure, but my axes background is gray. When I save with transparent=True both the figure AND the axes are given completely transparent backgrounds. But I wanted my axes to be gray. This post is old, but maybe someone will be able to help? I uploaded an example with and without transparency: http://imgur.com/a/aR3TF I want matplotlib to keep my gray axes background, but it removes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran your code on Matplotlib 1.5 and found that it produced the expected output for me. For all happening on upon this in the future I give two concise ways of achieving this below.

A quick note, you definitely don't want to set `transparent=True` as an option for savefig as this will override the facecolors as you can see in the matplotlib.figure.savefig [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L1648-L1660).

To actually solve your problem the second link you posted [How to set opacity of background colour of graph wit Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581504/how-to-set-opacity-of-background-colour-of-graph-wit-matplotlib) actually solves the problem. The issue with the code snippet in the question is the use of `fig.set_facecolor` as opposed to `fig.patch.set_facecolor`

## Fix 1:

From the above linked question use the facecolor argument to savefig

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('b') # instead of fig.patch.set_facecolor
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.5)

plt.plot([1,3], [1,3])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('method1.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())
```

## Fix 2:

You can also specify the savefig facecolor through the rcParams.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure()

col = 'blue'
#specify color of plot when showing in program. 
#fig.set_facecolor(col) also works
fig.patch.set_facecolor(col)
#specify color of background in saved figure
mpl.rcParams['savefig.facecolor'] = col 

#set the alpha for both plot in program and saved image
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.plot([1,3], [1,3])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('method2.png')
```

If you you would like your axes to have a background these solution should leave that background (such as produced by seaborn in Erotemic's comment) intact. If you want to be more explicit about it add:

```
ax.patch.set_color('palegoldenrod') # or whatever color you like
ax.patch.set_alpha(.7)
```

The axis patch alpha will transfer to savefig without extra effort.

Note that in both cases I used `plt.tight_layout()` to eliminate useless extra space in the saved figure. You can read more on that in the matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

Comment: Thank you. At this point, I'm not sure what version of Matplotlib I was running - presumably, based on the date, 1.3.1.  Good to know this can be made to work as expected now, and thanks for your thorough explanation.