# Pyplot: Drawing figure in a custom scale (both x and y)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been plotting a dataframe using the following code within a Jupyter Notebook: For comparision with older data only available on paper in the scale 0.005mm=1cm, I need to export and print the graph in the same scale: 0.005mm in the figure (both x and y-axis) have to be 1cm in the figure.

Is there any way how I can define a custom scale? For information, the x-range and y-range are not fixed, they will vary depending on the data I am loading into the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns            
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.7, 0], [1.75, -0.012], [1.8, 0]]),
                   columns=['pos', 'val'])      
            
# Plot results
sns.set()
plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))

plt.plot(df['pos'], df['val'])

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.xlabel('Position [mm]')
plt.ylabel('Höhe [mm]')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.005))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.005))

plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I imagine that to check against an old paper graph you want to print your plot, won't you? In this case you have to ① analyze your data before plotting and decide the size of the figure, in inches, to accomodate the Axes and ② knowing the Figure dpi, you can explicitly set the transformation between canvas coordinates, in pixels, and data coordinates (see the Transformation Tutorial in the Matplotlib documentation). If you succeed, I suggest that you post your solution as an answer because it's an interesting problem, OTOH if you are having problems ping me, I'll try to help more…

Comment: @gboffi: I tried working on the problem as you suggested. I defined x,y-limits and calculated the axis length in inch by (xmax-xmin)/0.005/2.54. I also read the transformation tutorial, but I do not get how converting data coordinates into pixel coordinates can help me with my problem. Could you go a little bit more into detail on what you exactly would do with with that?

Comment: I have tried for a while to walk my way in `matplotlib.transforms` module but it's a labyrinth of mirrors… I'm sorry but for the moment I will give up.  To answer your question you need a real Matplotlib developer, so I'd suggest to try to raise [an issue on Matplotlib's github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)

Comment: I've changed my mind re transforms and I've posted what I think it's a good, working answer.  Could you please have a look and tell me if it is, in some way, unsatisfactory?

Comment: Great solution. I had to change dpi=118 to dpi=100, but now the scale is exactly as I want it to be. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have the possibility to vote my answer (click the "▲" triangle on the left of it) or even to accept it (click the “✓” check mark on the left of my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010724/pyplot-drawing-figure-in-a-custom-scale-both-x-and-y#comment111429500_63010724)
I suggested to use `matplotlib.transforms` — well I was wrong, the way
to go is to **shamelessly steal** from Matplotlib's [Demo Fixed Size
Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_fixed_size_axes.html)…

[image]

(the figure was resized by StackOverflow to fit in the post, but you
can check that the proportions are correct)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Divider, Size
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.mpl_axes import Axes

cm = lambda d: d/2.54

x, y = [1700.0, 1725.0, 1750.0], [0.0, -12.0, 0.0] # μm
dx, dy = 50.0, 12.0

# take margins into account
xmin, xmax = min(x)-dx*0.05, max(x)+dx*0.05
ymin, ymax = min(y)-dy*0.05, max(y)+dy*0.05
dx, dy = xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin

# 5 μm data == 1 cm plot
scale = 5/1
xlen, ylen = dx/scale, dy/scale

# Now we know the extents of our data and the axes dimension,
# so we can set the Figure dimensions, taking borders into account
left, right = 2, 1
bot, top = 1.5, 1.5
fig = plt.figure(
    figsize=(cm(left+xlen+right), cm(bot+ylen+top)),
    dpi=118)

# change bg color to show so that one can measure the figure
# and the axes when pasted into SO and do their math…
fig.set_facecolor('xkcd:grey teal')

##########  Below is stolen from Matplotlib Fixed Size Axes
########## (please don't ask me…)
# Origin and size of the x axis and y axis
h = [Size.Fixed(cm(left)), Size.Fixed(cm(xlen))]
v = [Size.Fixed(cm(bot)), Size.Fixed(cm(ylen))]
divider = Divider(fig, (0.0, 0.0, 1., 1.), h, v, aspect=False)
# NB: Axes is from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.mpl_axes
ax = Axes(fig, divider.get_position())
ax.set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=1, ny=1))
fig.add_axes(ax)
#########  Above is stolen from Matplotlib Fixed Size Axes Demo 

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
ax.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax), yticks=range(-12,1,3),
       xlabel='X/μm', ylabel='Y/μm',
       title='X vs Y, 1 cm on plot equals 5 μm')
fig.suptitle('Figure dimensions: w = %.2f cm, h = %.2f cm.'%(
    left+xlen+right, bot+ylen+top))

fig.savefig('Figure_1.png',
            # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805178/2749397, Joe Kington's
            facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor='none')
```

Answer (score 0):

1 inch = 2.54 cm, so 254/0.005 = 50800 dpi

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,30), dpi=50800)
```

Comment: Tried replacing "plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))" with "plt.figure(figsize=(20,30), dpi=50800)" and got "ValueError: Image size of 1016000x1524000 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction."

Comment: I'll repeat myself with a triad of errors, but how do you respond with dpi=5080, or dpi=508, and then try to enlarge it at 1000% when printed?

Comment: Still get ValueError with 5080, but not with 508.

Comment: I'm going to print at DPI=508, and then I'll be able to respond with an enlarged copy of what I printed.