# Plot multiple graphs in matplotlib, setting labels and size of each graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I want to plot multiple graphs in a matrix (4,2) and I want that the figures at the left side have their labels in their left side and the opposite for the right side. Additionally, when I plot them in Google Colab, the graphs are all squished together, so I would like to increase their size and the spacing between them. And in the end, I would like that only the two graphs at the bottom have the x label.

Could anyone give me some tips on what functions or internal parameters to use? Additionally, there is some function where I can see my graphs in another window of my browser, instead of bellow my code box of Colab or something like this?

I would also be happy if you could give me tips to avoid unnecessary code.

This is my code, so far:

```
x = df_clean['SIO2']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2)

axs[0,0].plot(x, df_clean['AL2O3'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[0,1].plot(x, df_clean['MGO'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[1,0].plot(x, df_clean['FEOT'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[1,1].plot(x, df_clean['CAO'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[2,0].plot(x, df_clean['NA2O'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[2,1].plot(x, df_clean['K2O'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[3,0].plot(x, df_clean['TIO2'], 'bo', markersize=1)
axs[3,1].plot(x, df_clean['P2O5'], 'bo', markersize=1)

plt.suptitle('Harker Diagrams (All data)')
plt.figure(figsize=(60, 45))
```

And this is what I'm getting back:

[image: And this is what I'm getting back:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to determine specific position, orientation, size, color, etc. of axis labels use `ax.annotate()`. You can read the docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) about how to use it. There are way too many options to mention them all here but play around with it and you can get precise labels.

As for adjusting the spacing between the plots, use the `wspace` and `hspace` options of `fig.subplots_adjust()`, which you can read about [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

If you want the x axis label to appear only on the bottom you should use `sharex=True` when you initially call `plt.subplots()`. Also a good idea to set `sharey=True` if all your plots have the same y axis.

You can adjust the size of the overall diagram (which in turn will adjust the size of each individual plot) by setting `figsize=(width, height)` when you call `plt.subplots()`.

Not sure about getting the output to come up in a different browser window, but these functions should help you make a cleaner looking graph.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much, just one more thing, how do I put a background on my graph?

Comment: I would look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458251/plot-over-an-image-background-in-python/34459284) if you want to add a picture as a background or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804005/matplotlib-figure-facecolor-background-color) to see how to change the background color.